# Sonata User Bundle Gendre list error

Tags: symfony, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I have some issue with Sonata User Bundle. I want to update one user profile, but I got an error. I try to fix this but I can't: The Gender list renders results as shown below:

```
<select>
    <option value="gender_unknown">u</option>
    <option value="gender_female">f</option>
    <option value="gender_male">m</option>
</select>
```

But the datebase field is a 1 length varchar and it's required to be a `'u'`, `'f'` or `'m'`.
I think it has something to do with translations, but it's weird because it works in a local dev environment, which is the same as in the server (I use docker).